# How to style Android's onSearchRequested();

Tags: android, search, android-activity, styles

I cant figure out how to make the search dialog fit the height and look like the action bar (like on YouTube). Can you tell me how to do it?
Here's my Mainfest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.at_soft.zapiskiinfo" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".SearchableActivity"/>
</application>
```

Code when the button is clicked:

```
private void openSearch(){
    onSearchRequested();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And here's also my styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

</style>
</resources>
```

**Please take a look at this photo:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr64E.jpg

How to make it look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxTqy.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call below in OnCreate of activity:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
getActivity().getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.yourSearchBarLayout);
```

Comment: Is that for making it with Search widget, because I want to make it with Search Dialog? If it isn't what should my search bar layout contain ? Also on which OnCreate should I add it? MainActivity or SearchableActivity? Sorry but I'm newcomer to android app development and little bit confused.

Comment: Yes, add the SearchView to the layout that you created for setCustomView, and add the above code to the activity you want it to be shown.